# SSIS Import - Excel Connection Manager opening files on import

Tags: excel, ssis

Morning,

**Background:**  I have a very simple job that imports data from 3 xlsx files to 3 sql tables using ssis (VS 2013). I am on a large corporate network, so my scheduling capabilities are slim. I have been using an excel scheduler for 3 years with no real issues to speak of. The scheduler uses a batch file to fire off and kill various projects. The times do not overlap.

**Issue:**  That said, I have been having a really strange issue. On the above mentioned job, it runs fine when opening VS and running manually (99% of the time). When the scheduler fires off the job with the batch file, it OPENS all of the excel connections (the actual FILES open with a read write prompt) when it gets to that part of the ETL process!

**Final Word:**   I see it happening on the other packages where an excel connection manager exists (there are only 2 others out of 15). It appears to be opening upon data validation of the connection. Delay validation setting makes no difference (nor should it really in this case).

Has anyone ever seen this behavior? I am at a complete loss and its killing my vibe! :)

Thank you in advance,

Corey

Comment: Update, it seems to be doing it on excel validation. Just opens all the files!